# I have an array of integers, how do I use each one in a mysql query (in php)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array full of random content item ids. I need to run a mysql query (id in the array goes in the WHERE clause), using each ID that's in the array, in the order that they appear in the said array. How would I do this?

This will be an UPDATE query, for each individual ID in the array.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As with nearly all "How do I do SQL from within PHP" questions - You *really* should use prepared statements. It's not that hard:

```
$ids  = array(2, 4, 6, 8);

// prepare an SQL statement with a single parameter placeholder
$sql  = "UPDATE MyTable SET LastUpdated = GETDATE() WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

// bind a different value to the placeholder with each execution
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++)
{
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $ids[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Updated record ID: $id\n";
}

// done
$stmt->close();
```

Alternatively, you can do it like this:

```
$ids    = array(2, 4, 6, 8);

// prepare an SQL statement with multiple parameter placeholders
$params = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($ids), "?"));
$sql    = "UPDATE MyTable SET LastUpdated = GETDATE() WHERE id IN ($params)";
$stmt   = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

// dynamic call of mysqli_stmt::bind_param                    hard-coded eqivalent
$types = str_repeat("i", count($ids));                        // "iiii"
$args = array_merge(array($types), $ids);                     // ["iiii", 2, 4, 6, 8]
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), ref($args)); // $stmt->bind_param("iiii", 2, 4, 6, 8)

// execute the query for all input values in one step
$stmt->execute();

// done
$stmt->close();
echo "Updated record IDs: " . implode("," $ids) ."\n";

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// helper function to turn an array of values into an array of value references
// necessary because mysqli_stmt::bind_param needs value refereces for no good reason
function ref($arr) {
    $refs = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
    return $refs;
}
```

Add more parameter placeholders for other fields as you need them.

**Which one to pick?**

- The first variant works with a variable number of records iteratively, hitting the database multiple times. This is most useful for UPDATE and INSERT operations.
- The second variant works with a variable number of records too, but it hits the database only once. This is much more efficient than the iterative approach, obviously you can only do the same thing to all affected records. This is most useful for SELECT and DELETE operations, or when you want to UPDATE multiple records with the same data.

**Why prepared statements?**

- Prepared statements are a lot safer because they make SQL injection attacks impossible. This is the primary reason to use prepared statements, even if it is more work to write them. A sensible habit to get into is: Always use prepared statements, even if you think it's "not really necessary." Neglect will come and bite you (or your customers).
- Re-using the same prepared statement multiple times with different parameter values is more efficient than sending multiple full SQL strings to the database, because the database only needs to compile the statement once and can re-use it as well.
- Only parameter values are sent to the database on `execute()`, so less data needs to go over the wire when used repeatedly.

In longer loops the execution time difference between using a prepared statement and sending plain SQL will become noticeable.

Comment: Thats the strangest php syntax Ive ever seen. Had to loop up a bunch of those functions.

Comment: In the second method , where do we specify the data type for all the values of array?

Comment: The above solution did not work for me. http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli
<-- This worked like a charm.

Comment: @jackkorbin 27 people think it works just fine, you think it does not work. I think that means you made a mistake.

Comment: Well i tried it all ways , it did not work. There is a possibility that Your code might became outdated as it is from 2008. Moreover the 2nd method does not bind the type of variables from array.

Comment: Could you supply a link to pastebin (or equivalent) so I can have a look at your code and if necessary update my answer?

Comment: @Tomalak shouldn't `'bindparams'` be `'bind_param'`?  I think this is what jackkorbin was getting at. (after I compared yours with his link) Please confirm what is correct.  Thanks.

Comment: @mickmack I think you are right - the function is named `bind_param`. I've updated my code.

Comment: and where is the `s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob` part? and the variables by reference?  This doesn't seem complete to me.  You may have misled 27 people (or maybe everyone is just using the first code block)

Comment: The answer is from 2008. Can it be that PHP has substantially changed its mysqli API since then?

Comment: I don't have any reason to believe that this is a php version issue.  Your 2nd solution really seems incomplete to me.  Because this answer has a green tick and so many upvotes, I would urge you to prioritize fixing this up.

Comment: @mickmack I think the issues are addressed now. Wrote a better blurb of text, too,

Comment: I didn't have a chance to actually test.  Did you test? This other answer seems to insist that passing by reference is required. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713481/2943403 (and I have read this remark in a few other posts around the web.)  I am still researching this topic for my own benefit.  Have a look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047265/2943403

Comment: You can eliminate the need for the `ref()` function by using the splat operator (introduced in PHP 5.6) `$stmt->bind_param(...$args)`

Answer (score 2):

## Using the "IN" Clause

Might be what you're after

```
$ids = array(2,4,6,8);
$ids = implode($ids);
$sql="SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN($ids);";
mysql_query($sql);
```

otherwise, what's wrong with

```
$ids = array(2,4,6,8);
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ID = $id;";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: He said it would become an UPDATE statement. After your answer was posted, though.

Comment: Why would the OP want to query `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN(2468)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Amen to Tomalak's comment on statements.

However, if you do not wish to use mysqli, you can always use intval() to prevent injection:

```
$ids  = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE MyTable SET LastUpdated = GETDATE() WHERE id = " . intval($ids[$i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$values_filtered = array_filter('is_int', $values);
if (count($values_filtered) == count($values)) {
    $sql = 'update table set attrib = 'something' where someid in (' . implode(',', $values_filtered) . ');';
    //execute
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following, however you need to be VERY careful that the array only contains integers otherwise you could end up with SQL injection.

You really don't want to be doing multiple queries to get the content out if you can help it. Something like this might be what you are after.

```
foreach ($array as $key = $var) {
   if ((int) $var <= 0) {
       unset($array[$key]);
   }
}


$query = "SELECT * 
from content 
WHERE contentid IN ('".implode("','", $array)."')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Its an admin-only function, so nobody except myself would be executing it. I need to run an UPDATE query for every ID in the array.