# How can I create a dynamic mysql query by using the values in an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new on `php` and `mysql`. I found several things that I can use - such as implode- on internet but I couldn't make it. I will try to be clear as much as I can.

First table name: `mylist`

column name: `id` (The values on this column are unique.) (incremental)

I put all ids inside an array called `myIds`. The array contains only unique integer values and it's length is 800.

I need to get answers for each ids from another table for the current date. This table also contain `id` column but for an `id`, there can be more than one answer.

For example: today, there are 3 answers for id 1 and 5 answers for id 4, etc.

Second table name: `answerlist`

This is the query works for a specified id:

```
$sql = "SELECT `answer` FROM `answerlist` WHERE `type`= 'Help' AND `id` = 1 AND DATE(`added`) = DATE (NOW())";
```

I would like to create a dynamic query which gets id values from the above array. How can I do this?

Comment: Which mysql driver are you using? mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Using PDO with IN clause array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)

Answer (score 0):

A Solution would be to use The mysql IN operations for your ids

```
SELECT `answer`, `id` FROM `answerlist` WHERE `type`= 'Help' AND `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND DATE(`added`) = DATE (NOW())
```

you can implode them like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT `answer`, `id` FROM `answerlist` WHERE `type`= 'Help' AND `id` IN (" . implode(',', $myIds) . ") AND DATE(`added`) = DATE (NOW())";
```

Comment: I think your solution is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should use prepared query instead

Comment: That is kind of correct if the User can change the ids, i just went with the idea that this is not the case. IF The user can change the ids then indeed he should check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772913/how-do-you-use-in-clauses-with-mysqli-prepared-statements