# How to build a WHERE condition with multiple values from checkbox?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which has a checkbox with three options i.e. `'A'`,`'B'` and `'C'`. I need to build a `SELECT` statement to get data from a database table X, for which the `WHERE` clause could be `WHERE field1 IN ('A','B','C')` or it could be any one of the values i.e. `WHERE field1 = 'A'` etc.

I am kind of stuck as to how to proceed with the `SELECT` statement.

Please let me know if any more details are required to understand the problem.

The code for my checkbox in the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="Male" id="Male"> Male
<input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="Female" id="Female"> Female
<input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="Other" id="Other"> Other
```

The SELECT statement would basically be like :

```sql
SELECT field1,field2,field3
FROM X 
WHERE field1 IN('A','B','C')
```

or it could be

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3
FROM X
WHERE field1 ='A' -- Basically this could be a single value.
```

Comment: What is your problem? It's not clear.

Comment: @WilliamGunawan the problem is building the WHERE clause based on the values of the checkbox values selected i.e. either one value or all values.

Comment: You query already correct nothing wrong with it. so after you execute the quest it's not same as you expected? can you tell us more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772913/how-do-you-use-in-clauses-with-mysqli-prepared-statements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN ('".implode("','", $_POST['gender'])."')";
```

This is how you could build your query, but it is strongly recommended you sanitize the content of the $_POST array before building the query, because you could be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Don't put user inputs directly into SQL queries.

Comment: well this is a whole other question, but of course, you are right !

Comment: The more times people put answers like this on SO, the more vulnerable websites get built...

Comment: @lufc I agree, my bad ! Still, it does answer the OP, so shouldn't it be enough to mention the vulnerability like I did in my edit ?

Comment: Any comment on the downvotes ? Did i miss understood the question ?

Comment: Guys this is just an example. I am taking care of SQL injection. No issues with that. I just need to know how to handle the multiple values of the checkbox  in the WHERE clause . All other precautions are taken care of in my code.

Comment: good to know !  at first i didn’t mention the vulnerability, this is what probably got me the downvotes :) still i understand, it is important to mention, you seem to know what you are doing but it’s not necessarily the case for anyone who could use this post in the future !

Comment: @DavidD'Lima, did it solved your problem finally ? Was not sure if you meant you wanted strictly either 1 or all checkboxes at a time… Anyway i can edit if there is something missing, or if you were waiting to see if something else comes up before accepting an answer, it's totally cool too.

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé it could be either one value or multiple values. Just trying out your solution.

Comment: @DavidD'Lima - the best way to take care of SQL injection is to use prepared statements. This approach will not work with prepared statements.

Comment: @lufc yes I am aware that this will not work with prepared statements.

Comment: @lufc The OP does not mention anything about « The best way to avoid SQL injection » You’re being completely out of line here. It was more than enough to add a warning about the vulnerability in my answer. I think it’s important you realize that prepared statement are for security purposes, which also means that if you want to optimize the performance of your code, you must avoid them whenever it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite understanding what you actually want to do there, but as the comments already say, don't put user-inputs directly into mysql query.
As far as I understand you, this might help:

If you don't know how to establish a connection with pdo : https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM X WHERE field1 = :a OR field1 = :b OR field1 = :c);
$stmt->execute(['a'=> $aVariable,'b'=> $bVariable,'c'=>$cVariable]); //Here you bind the data from your form to the parameters of the select query.
$row = $stmt->fetch(); //This is the result of the mysql query with the data of the table
```