# prepared statement in the loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli

I have a problem that i cant figure out for too long. Basically I have table with usernames (1 unique username in the table) with 1 respective image file. Some of users have image file and some dont. usernames are stored in the array $Users[]. I am trying to fetch filenames of images for each user using:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT file_name FROM images WHERE BINARY username=?"); 
    for($temp1=0; $temp1<count($Users); $temp1++){
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $Users[$temp1]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($ImgFileName);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $imageURL[$temp1]=$ImgFileName;
    }
```

however this has annoying behavior. Say as code loops through, if user User[0] has $ImgFileName related to it, but User[1], User[2] etc doesnt, then $ImgFileName is used of the last user with available image, instead of null. This happens until some user in the loop again has image filename in the table. So if i print $imageURL[] array after loops goes through, it looks smth like:

```
$Users[]=[user1,user2,user3,user4,user5]
$imageURL[]=[img001.png,img001.png,img001.png,img231.png,img124.png,img124.png]
```

instead of

```
$Users[]=[user1,user2,user3,user4,user5]
$imageURL[]=[img001.png,,,img231.png,img124.png,]
```

anyone knows why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be 10x easier to just do it with PDO. Any reason why you are doing this with mysqli?

Comment: am actually just learning php, javascript by doing some project and havent really used pdo . but will have a look. thank you

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Thanks. Is one way of another better from sql injection point of view? Or maybe any other safety features?

Comment: No, security-wise they are the same. Both offer prepared statements, PDO has just more features which makes coding much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because you never reset `$ImgFileName` inside the loop.

Put `$ImgFileName = null;` inside the loop.

You can also unset the variable, which will result in the same outcome.

```
for($temp1=0; $temp1<count($Users); $temp1++){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $Users[$temp1]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($ImgFileName);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $imageURL[$temp1]=$ImgFileName;

    unset($ImgFileName);
}
```

Comment: hmmm, weird, i tried and indeed it works. i expected that whenever sql statement gives null, which it does if i just run it for one user with no filename, then it would automatically bind  $ImgFileName = null;. Glad I asked, because I wasnt expecting that. Many Thanks, Ser.

Comment: @lucaamarelli When a prepared statement doesn't find any rows, it won't return any value, not even null.

Comment: yea, now i can see. lesson learned. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to store the file name in an array with the name as the index (along with ensuring that the image name is blanked out each time)...

```
for($temp1=0; $temp1<count($Users); $temp1++){
    $ImgFileName = '';
    $userName = $Users[$temp1];
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($ImgFileName);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $imageURL[$userName] = $ImgFileName;
}
```

If you also combine this with using `in` (from [How do you use IN clauses with mysqli prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772913/how-do-you-use-in-clauses-with-mysqli-prepared-statements)) you could just fetch a list of the known users and filenames in one execution...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username, file_name
                       FROM images 
                       WHERE username in...
```

just loop through the results and add them into an array.