# How to bind N number of parameters using mysqli prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli

In old mysql code, I had a query below which worked perfectly which is below:

```
$questioncontent = (isset($_GET['questioncontent'])) ? $_GET['questioncontent'] : '';

$searchquestion = $questioncontent;
$terms = explode(" ", $searchquestion);

$questionquery = "
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, an.Answer, r.ReplyType, 
  FROM Answer an 
  INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
  JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
  JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 

                 WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each) {     
        $i++;         

        if ($i == 1){         
            $questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE `%$each%` ";     
            } else {         
                $questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE `%$each%` ";    
                 } 
                 }  

                 $questionquery .= "GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY "; $i = 0; foreach ($terms as $each) {     
                     $i++;      

        if ($i != 1)         
        $questionquery .= "+";     
        $questionquery .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE `%$each%` ,1,0)"; 
        } 

        $questionquery .= " DESC ";
```

But since that old mysql is fading away that people are saying to use PDO or mysqli (Can't use PDO because of version of php I have currently got), I tried changing my code to mysqli, but this is giving me problems. In the code below I have left out the bind_params command, my question is that how do I bind the parameters in the query below? It needs to be able to bind multiple `$each` because the user is able to type in multiple terms, and each `$each` is classed as a term.

Below is current mysqli code on the same query:

```
     $questioncontent = (isset($_GET['questioncontent'])) ? $_GET['questioncontent'] : '';

        $searchquestion = $questioncontent;
        $terms = explode(" ", $searchquestion);

        $questionquery = "
        SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, an.Answer, r.ReplyType, 
          FROM Answer an 
          INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
          JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
          JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 

                         WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each) {     
                $i++;         

                if ($i == 1){         
  $questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";     
                    } else {         
  $questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";    
                         } 
                         }  

 $questionquery .= "GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY "; $i = 0; foreach ($terms as $each) {     
                             $i++;      

                if ($i != 1)         
                $questionquery .= "+";     
                $questionquery .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0)"; 
                } 

                $questionquery .= " DESC ";



            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionquery);      
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionId,$dbQuestionContent,$dbOptionType,$dbAnswer,$dbReplyType); 
            $questionnum = $stmt->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913899/mysqli-binding-params-using-call-user-func-array) that talks about the use of [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) with `bind_param()`.

From the [PHP Docs on mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) it says the following...

> **Note:**
>
> Care must be taken when using mysqli_stmt_bind_param() in conjunction
> with call_user_func_array(). Note that mysqli_stmt_bind_param()
> requires parameters to be passed by reference, whereas
> call_user_func_array() can accept as a parameter a list of variables
> that can represent references or values.

You'll want to use something like this

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $terms);
```

and it's up to you to ensure that the correct number of `?` characters appear in your SQL string `$stmt`.

**[EDIT]**

Here's a working example

```
// user entered search strings
$user_terms = array("a", "b", "c");

// append your wildcard "%" to all elements. you must use "&" reference on &$value
foreach ($user_terms as &$value) {
    $value = '%'.$value.'%';
}

$types = "";
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($user_terms); $i++) {
    $types .= "s";
}

$terms = array_merge( array($types), $user_terms);

// the array $terms now contains: { "sss", "%a%", "%b%", "%c%" }

$sql = "SELECT ... ?,?,?"    // edit your sql here

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $terms);
```

Comment: I will give it a go but I am guessing the line of code will be something like this:`call_user_func_array( array ($stmt, 'bind_param'), $each); `? Also do I need to concatenate % with the $each as it is a LIKE statement? Could it be like this instead `call_user_func_array( array ($stmt, 'bind_param'), $each = '%' . $each . '%'); `?

Comment: Ok, I tried this: `call_user_func_array( array ($stmt, 'bind_param'), $each = '%' . $each . '%'); ` but if I enter in a correct term such as 'AAA', it cannot find the result as in the old mysql code, it did find the result

Comment: Updated answer with working code. The trick is to make sure the `$types` variable has the same number of `s` chars as your search $user_terms which must also match the number of `?` chars in the `$sql`