# PHP PreparedStatements field names

Tags: php, mysql, database, prepared-statement

Is there a way you can set field names in php prepared statements, instead of just setting there values, for example,

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE movies SET filmName = ?, 
   filmDescription = ?, 
  filmImage = ?,  
  filmPrice = ?,  
  filmReview = ?  
   WHERE filmID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sssdii',
  $_POST['filmName'],
  $_POST['filmDescription'],
  $_POST['filmImage'],
  $_POST['filmPrice'], 
  $_POST['filmReview'],
  $_POST['filmID']);
 $stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

is there a simpler way to do that? For example, is there a way I can do something like

```
 $stmt->bind_param($_POST);
```

so it binds everything in with the correct names?

Comment: Not as standard, but you could easily write your own wrapper to do so.... of course, what happens to `$_POST['submit']`?

Comment: Yes, there is a simpler way: use PDO, which takes a list of values per `->execute([...]);`

Comment: @gbvisconti String,...,Decimal,Integer...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. I did not test, but if I missed something, please comment and I will edit.

```
$sql = "UPDATE 
            movies 
        SET 
            filmName = ?, 
            filmDescription = ?, 
            filmImage = ?,  
            filmPrice = ?,  
            filmReview = ?  
        WHERE 
            filmID = ?";

$arrayFields = array("filmName" => "s"
                    , "filmDescription" => "s"
                    , "filmImage" => "s"
                    , "filmPrice" => "d"
                    , "filmReview" => "i"
                    , "filmID" => "i");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {

    if(array_key_exists ( $key , $arrayFields )) {

        $stmt->bind_param($arrayFields[$key], $_POST[$key]);
    }
}
$stmt->execute();   

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: wouldnt be nice if this was possible, unfortunately this wont work with mysqli

Comment: What if instead of '?' he uses :filmName, for example? Is it possible in mysqli? Then it's just use the $key inside the loop to bind it

Comment: only PDO allows that, I modified your code to show how to do it in PDO

Comment: hummm, I will try to edit my answer considering that restriction in mysqli

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486032/binding-an-unknown-number-of-parameters-using-mysqli

Comment: the problem is mysqli is like fake OOP, its not flexible, there are way to write custom functions but it is messy. thats why people ditch it in favor of PDO