# Prepared statements when working with set operations

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got a simple query that is not so easy to execute in PHP script:

```
SELECT `title` from `MY_TABLE` WHERE id in (30,32,33,44)
```

Usually I execute sql queries with prepared statements. I place a bunch of `?` and than bind parameters. This time the numbers in parenthesis are an array of data I get from the user.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$ids = [30,32,33,44];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("

SELECT `title` from `MY_TABLE` WHERE id in (?)

");
// $stmt->bind_param();
$stmt->bind_param("i",$ids);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);
$stmt->store_result();
//fetch
```

How can I execute a set operation with prepared statements?

UPDATE:

After following your advice I came up with this

```
$ids = [30,32,33,44];
$questionMarks  = rtrim(str_repeat('?,',count($ids)),", ");
$parameters = str_repeat('i',count($ids));
echo $questionMarks."<br>";
echo $parameters."<br>";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("

SELECT `title` from `MY_TABLE` WHERE id in (".$questionMarks.")

");

$scene_names = [];
$stmt->bind_param($parameters, $ids); //error here
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);
$stmt->store_result();
```

I am still getting an error. This time it says:

```
Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables
```

I am not sure why it thinks that the number of elements (what is element in this case?) is wrong.

UPDATE 2:

Instead of:

```
$stmt->bind_param($parameters, $ids); //error here
```

I used:

```
$stmt->bind_param($parameters, ...$ids); //error gone
```

Taraam. Works fine.

Comment: You need the same amount of `?` as elements in the array

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$ids = [30,32,33,44];
$types = array();
foreach($ids as $i){
    array_push($types,'i');
}
$params = array_merge($ids,$types);
$sqlIN  = str_repeat('?,',count($ids));
$sqlIN  = rtrim($sqlIN, ',');

//Value of $sqlIN now looks like ?,?,?,?

$sql = "SELECT title from MY_TABLE WHERE id IN ($sqlIN)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: Thanks. We are almost there. There is unfortunately one error left. See updated question.

Comment: Sorry I'm used to PDO where you can just pass an array of elements, I'll check the mysqli documentation and get back to you

Comment: Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913899/mysqli-binding-params-using-call-user-func-array) to guide me... I would highly recommend looking at using PDO, very similar but much better functionality. There is probably a much cleaner solution out there for mysqli

Comment: Thanks. didn't work, but that post actually contains the correct answer. It involves using splat operator

Comment: Glad to know you got it sorted! I was in new waters with mysqli