# XML to database - foreach loop to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach, simplexml

I am fetching a XML-file with simpleXML and I want to store those values inside my database with a foreach loop. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string('XML-FILE');

foreach ($xml->METADATA->DATA as $item) {
    foreach ($item->children() as $child) {
        $sel_stmt = "INSERT INTO dwh_xml (".$child->getName().") VALUES ('".$child."') ";
        directSQL($sel_stmt);
    }
}
?>
```

My XML file looks like this:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
    <METADATA>
        <DATA>
            <FIELD_1>001</FIELD_1>
            <FIELD_2>ENTRY_2</FIELD_2>
            <FIELD_3>ENTRY_3</FIELD_3>
            <FIELD_4>ENTRY_4</FIELD_4>
            <FIELD_5>ENTRY_5</FIELD_5>
            <FIELD_6>000003</FIELD_6>
            <FIELD_7>ENTRY_7</FIELD_7>
            <FIELD_8>ENTRY_8</FIELD_8>
            <FIELD_9>ENTRY_9</FIELD_9>
            <FIELD_10>ENTRY_10</FIELD_10>
            <FIELD_11>ENTRY_11</FIELD_11>
            <FIELD_12>ENTRY_12</FIELD_12>
            <FIELD_13>ENTRY_13</FIELD_13>
        </DATA>
    <METADATA>
</xml>
```

The import to my database is working but for each value it generates a new entry and I do not know how my above code must be changed so that it will become a single entry inside my database with one id. Here is a screenshot of my test entry:

[image]

And here you can see what it should look like:
[image]

I know that I am doing something wrong with my foreach loop and I know it may be easy for some of you guys but right now I am unable to fix it by myself. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May you share some code with me? I am using mysqli instead of PDO. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: the one before has right, but also the loop i for date try to make it for the field...just suppose that you have more values in one field,,,and it will work

Comment: okay thanks @user3783243! Looking forward to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the full query outside the inner most `foreach`. Something like this will be a good start. This thread should be able to help you to get the binding to work with `mysqli`, [MySQLI binding params using call_user_func_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913899/mysqli-binding-params-using-call-user-func-array). With PDO you'd just pass `$params` to the `execute` function.

```
foreach ($xml->METADATA->DATA as $item) {
    foreach ($item->children() as $child) {
        $cols[] = $child->getName();
        $params[] = $child->nodeValue;
    }
    if(!empty($params)) {
         $columns = implode(',', $cols);
         $placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($params)), ', ');
         $sql = 'INSERT INTO dwh_xml ( ' . $columns . ') VALUES(' . $placeholders . ')';
         $stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute();
         unset($params, $cols, $placeholders);
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/nhJi7

Comment: thanks for your help. Your code seems to work fine but I am unable to achieve an entry inside my database. I always get the error: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". Any idea why? Doest it has something to do with my auto increment ID column? Do you have an idea?

Comment: If this is using PDO - then you can pass the parameters in `$stmt->execute($params);`

Comment: got it working with PDO. Thank you very much for your help.