# What do & symbol and call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $value) do in php?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, php-5.4

I want to do `myqsli_stmt_bind_param` using `call_user_func_array()`, because I have dynamically values that should be passed to the query.

First, I tried just directly put my `$bind_params[] = [$type, $value]` (without &) as second parameter of `call_user_func_array()`. 
And second try I put my `$bind_params[] = [&$type, &$value]` as second parameter of `call_user_func_array()`.

My first trial is this (without &):

```
// To store all collected type into $bind_params[].
$bind_params = array($bind_params_1);

$count = count($bind_params_2);

// To store the all values into $bind_params[].
// $bind_params_2[] is collected $_POST values.
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    $bind_params[] = $bind_params_2[$i]; 
    $i++;
}

// Doing $stmt->bind_params($bind_params_1, $bind_params_2).
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $bind_params);
$stmt->execute();
```

If I run above code, this will produce a warning and an error:

> Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a
>   reference, value given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\x\xx\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx\gb_daftar_usulan.php on
>   line 571
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\x\xx\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx\gb_daftar_usulan.php on
>   line 584

And then my second trial look like this (with &) :

```
// To store all collected type into $bind_params[].
$bind_params = array(&$bind_params_1);

// $bind_params_2[] is collected $_POST values.
$count = count($bind_params_2);

// To store the all values into $bind_params[].
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    $bind_params[] = &$bind_params_2[$i]; 
    $i++;
}

// Doing $stmt->bind_params($bind_params_1, $bind_params_2).
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $bind_params);
$stmt->execute();
```

The second code produce the right one result for me.
I found this approach from here : (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713481).

Why was this happened ?

What do exactly `&` in `&$bind_params_1` and `&$bind_params_2` mean?

Why my first trial gave a warning and an error?

Comment: Read the PHP documentation of [references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: Did you see the other answer in the thread you linked? This one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682298/1839439

Comment: @Barmar i knew &$var in order to change $var variable if it's called by a function.
But i don't undertand why this was happened.
Because i  did "echo"  both of $bind_params[] in those two trials, those returned the same array elements.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for your suggesting Brother. But unfortunately my company still want to use this php version, :(

Answer (score -1):

The & reference to a variable, 
this means it gives the address in the memory to the function() and doesn't copy the value into a new part of the memory. How it works look here:
[Passing by Reference -> PHP-Docu](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)
and as @Brama toled, read how [References](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) work

You can find descriptions with examples to the function in the PHP-Documentation
[call_user_func_array ()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func-array.php)

It returns the return value of the callback or FALSE on error.

```
Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\x\xx\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx\gb_daftar_usulan.php on line 571

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\x\xx\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx\gb_daftar_usulan.php on line 584
```

The warning means the expected parameter can not be processed, for this reason, the Fatal error, because `fetch_assoc()` expects a correct DB-result

You can prevent this with:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}

/* free result set */
$result->free();
}
```

[source: PHP-Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc)

Comment: Please read [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @Janick Koder I've tried your suggested code sir. But the warning still come up.

` 
Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\x\xx\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx\gb_daftar_usulan.php on line 552
`
Mybe i should use reference (&$bind_params). Shouldn't i brother ?

Comment: @Dharman :Thanks for your suggested reference link. It would be worthy.