# Retrieve articles from array of category ids

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of category ids and want to retrieve articles from my mysql database with these category ids. What is the best method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here:

- [I have an array of integers, how do I use each one in a mysql query (in php)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php)

for a safe, parameter-based approach and code sample.

Answer (score 8):

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category_id IN (\''.implode('\'',array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$categories)).'\')');
```

Specify how articles are joined to categories if this is not how your db/table setup.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is not needed, 'tis better to use just intval function here.

Comment: intval would be preferred when talking about integers indeed, OP didn't mention that though (and using uuid's or even chars for categories is not that rare,) so just to be safe...