# Can't find an escaped string in the data base

Tags: php, mysql

In the database I have a string like this: `Caisse primaire d'assurance maladie`

Now when I try to look for it in my PHP script, it returns no items.

```
$array=array("Caisse primaire d'assurance maladie","Mairies","Hotels");
$in_list = "'".implode("','",$array)."'";

$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT libelle,activite,adresse,tel,lat,lng FROM etablissements where type IN ('.$in_list.')');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($libelle,$activite,$adresse,$tel,$lat,$lng);//the $stmt is empty
```

Now, if i try to look for `Mairies` only or `Hotels` only it would return me a result. That mean that the apostrophe is preventing my prepared query from running correctly. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can try replace ' with '' (two single quote) and try..

Comment: Yes, the apostrophe is causing a syntax error in the query. That's what prepared statements are supposed to prevent. Unfortunately you're not using prepared statements, you're just using regular old, SQL injection prone, syntax breaking string concatenation. What MySQL extension in particular are you using? MySQLi? PDO?

Comment: show us $in_list content

Comment: Then please see here for correct usage of MySQLi with prepared statements and `WHERE IN`: [I have an array of integers, how do I use each one in a mysql query (in php)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php)

Comment: Caisse primaire d'assurance maladie => Caisse primaire d''assurance maladie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i fix this.

By using a **real** prepared query, not just *mocking* it.

Or by escaping your strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` function to escape your query first.

Answer (score 1):

The string "Caisse primaire d'assurance maladie" has a single quotes in it.Maybe this single quotes ends your sql string unexpectedly.
I suggest you to print your sql statement first to check if it is correct.:)