# mysqli_query "where = $some_array" need just one match

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have an array of integers, how do I use each one in a mysql query (in php)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php)

I am trying to create some filtering function and I would like to know if it is possible, within a mysqli query, to check if the table row has a value equal to just one of those in the array. I hope the code will make it clearer:

```
$age=array(37,35);
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age = $age");
```

So I want the query to return all the rows of users whose age is either 37 or 35, but the above code doesn't work.

Using

```
...WHERE age = 35 OR age = 37"
```

Won't do, because I want it to be dynamic so to speak.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause.

SQL Example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE age IN (35, 37)
```

PHP Example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age IN (" . implode(',', array_map('intval', $age)) . ")";
```

**Note:** Be mindful of [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: You're my hero. Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: If an answer was helpful, please click the check mark to the left of the answer (It will turn green) so the person helping gets the proper credit.

Comment: The timer didn't allow me to 5 minutes ago, but I came back to do it right now. Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

```
$age=array(37,35); 
$age_str=implode(',',$age);
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age in ($age_str)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the php [join](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) method together with an IN clause in the SQL

```
$age=array(37,35);
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age IN (".join(",", $age).")");
```

Comment: Note that `join()` is an alias for `implode()`. I recommend using the root function.

Comment: it's an alias of implode - I tend to use it for readability as implode isn't obvious to me. maybe that's just me though...

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age IN (" . implode(",",$age) . ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [in](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause.

```
$ageArr = implode(',',$age);
SELECT * FROM users WHERE age IN ($ageArr);
```