# I have an array of dates, how do I use each one in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a array of dates. For each date, I want to insert it into the where clause of a query, then store the resulting value (a count of something) into a new table.

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php) provides an answer in php, but I need to do this strictly in mysql. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: by array, I just mean a list of things. For instance, a table with one row of date values. Thanks.

Comment: mySQL doesn't have array variables (I don't think)

Comment: Do you mean stored procedures?

Comment: perhaps the answer is to just use a different tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli bind\_param for array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226762/mysqli-bind-param-for-array-of-strings)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703180/use-an-array-in-a-mysqli-prepared-statement-where-in-query

Answer (score 0):

iterate the array and build your where clause?

something like:

```
$where = "WHERE";
foreach($date as $dates){
$where .= " AND " . $date . = " some column";
}
```