# MySql Query results from multiple select form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a form on a html page which allows me to select multiple items. The name of the form is  name="region[]

It posts to another page where I use this code:

```
The region(s) selected:
<?php
$values = $_POST['region'];

foreach ($values as $region){
echo $region;
}
?>
```

This will display the results of the form perfectly; if there is one value it will print the one value, but if there is more than one then it will print them all.

I need to use the results of this in a query:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("****","****","****","****");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT
GoogleBusinessData.BusName,
GoogleBusinessData.BusAddress,
PostcodeTbl.PostcodeFirstTown,
PostcodeTbl.PostcodeFirstArea,
PostcodeTbl.Region,
PostcodeTbl.Postcode,
PostcodeTbl.PostcodeFirstLetters,
PostcodeTbl.PostcodeFirstPart,
PostcodeTbl.Country,
GoogleBusinessData.BusPhone,
GoogleBusinessData.BusCats,
GoogleBusinessData.FaroukCat,
GoogleBusinessData.BusWebsite,
GoogleBusinessData.BusDescription,
GoogleBusinessData.BusGoogleBusinessID,
GoogleBusinessData.BusPageURL,
EmailTable.EmailNumberOfEmails,
EmailTable.EmailAddresses
FROM
GoogleBusinessData
INNER JOIN PostcodeTbl ON GoogleBusinessData.BusPostalCode = PostcodeTbl.Postcode
INNER JOIN EmailTable ON GoogleBusinessData.BusWebsite = EmailTable.EmailWebsite
WHERE EmailTable.EmailNumberOfEmails > 0 AND
GoogleBusinessData.FaroukCat = 'Wedding Planner'
GROUP BY
GoogleBusinessData.BusWebsite
ORDER BY
GoogleBusinessData.BusName ASC
LIMIT 0,20");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['BusName'] . "  -  " . $row['PostcodeFirstTown'] . "  -  " . $row['PostcodeFirstArea'] . "  -  " . $row['Region'] . "  -  " . $row['Postcode'];
echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So I need to add the condition in the WHERE to only return the results if it contains one of the regions with the form. I tried the following with no joy:

```
WHERE PostcodeTbl.Region IN ('$region') AND
EmailTable.EmailNumberOfEmails > 0 AND
GoogleBusinessData.FaroukCat = 'Wedding Planner'
```

But this only returns the last selection (as if there were only one selected).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In your first script, you are looping through the items. Each item is put into the variable `$region` one by one. So after the loop, `$region` contains the last item. If you construct the `where` clause at that time, it explains why the query only returns the last item.

To fix this, you'll have to construct a variable (e.g. `$regions`) that contains a list of regions.

For instance:

```
$regions = "'" . implode($_POST['region'], "','") . "'";

...  WHERE PostcodeTbl.Region IN ('$regions') AND ...
```

Note that this is potentially unsafe, since the input in $_POST is not validated, so it is better to loop through the array (like you did) and validate each item one by one while constructing the string in `$regions`. You can use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for that.

Alternatively, and arguably better, is to use the parameter binding capabilities of mysqli. This is a bit tricky with array variables, but the details on how to do that are already described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226762/mysqli-bind-param-for-array-of-strings).

Comment: I tried to add the two lines of code but it won't return any results to anything.