# MySQLi with OR condition array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Say an array variable `$i` which contains the serial numbers. Example: `$i=array("1", "15", "20", "23");` This variable is set by `$_POST`.

And the MySQLi query is such to delete the rows which serial numbers exists in the array. i.e. If serial number = 1 or 15 or 20 or 23, delete the row. How to write it as a single MySQLi prepared statement?

I tried with `foreach`, but the that logic will do query for n number of times, where n is the size of the array.

```
foreach($i as $sno)// Only the logic I use
{
    DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `sno`=?
    bind_param("i", $sno);
    execute();
}
```

How can this simplified so the query can be re-written as `sno=[1] or [2] or [3] or ... [n]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli bind\_param for array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226762/mysqli-bind-param-for-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)**

Here is the logic,

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE sno IN ($i)
```

Comment: Out of all possible answers this one is fabulous.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Is tht a satire or recommendation?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually. Nobody cares either way.