# Looping multiple variable in mysqli bind parrram

Tags: php, search, mysqli, full-text-search

I try to create search result page with pagination, the pagination works fine, but i have problem with multiple word search and mysqli_stmt::bind_param():

So, here's my url: http://localhost/pg/page.php?k=hello+buddy

And this is page.php code:

```
 <?php
// Script and tutorial written by Adam Khoury @ developphp.com
// Line by line explanation : youtube.com/watch?v=T2QFNu_mivw
include 'koneksi.php';
// This first query is just to get the total count of rows
$param = '%'.$_GET['k'].'%';
$khusus = ''.$_GET['k'].'';
$z = explode(" ", $khusus);
$c = 'judul LIKE ?';
$d = ' OR judul LIKE ?';
$g = 's';
$v = 's';
$f = '%$z[0]%';
$o = '$z[';
$j = ']';
for ($i = 1; $i < count($z); ++$i) {
$x = $o . $i . $j;
$c = $c . ' ' . $d;
$f = $f . ', ' . $x;
$g = $g . '' . $v;
}
$stmt=$con->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM import WHERE '.$c.'');
$stmt->bind_param(''.$g.'', $f);
// Don't use bind_result()...
// execute your statement
$stmt->execute();
// Get result set into a MySQLi result resource
$result = $stmt->bind_result($id);

// array to hold all rows
$rows = array();

// All results bound to output vars
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  // Append an array containing your result vars onto the rowset array
  $rows[] = array(
    'id' => $id
  );
}
  $rows=$id;


// This is the number of results we want displayed per page
$page_rows = 10;
// This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
// Establish the $pagenum variable
$pagenum = 1;
// Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
// This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
if ($pagenum < 1) { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}
$dynamicList = "";

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id,judul,harga FROM import WHERE '.$c.' ORDER BY judul LIMIT ?,? ');
$begin= ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows;
$end= $page_rows;
$stmt->bind_param(''.$g.'ii', $f, $begin, $end);
$stmt->execute();
        /* store result */
        $stmt->store_result();
        /* get the row count */
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
        if ($count >= 1) {
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $judul, $harga);
// This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
$textline1 = "Products (<b>$rows</b>)";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to 
       the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
       generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?k='.$khusus.'&q='.$khususs.'&pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?k='.$khusus.'&q='.$khususs.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the target page number, but without it being a link
    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
    // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?k='.$khusus.'&q='.$khususs.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?k='.$khusus.'&q='.$khususs.'&pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}


while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                "$id, $judul, $harga,";
                $dynamicList .= "
                <li><div class='product'>
                <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='info'>
                <span class='holder'>
                <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg' alt='$judul' />
                <span class='book-name'>$judul</span>
                </a>
                 <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'>RM<span class='price'>$harga</span></a>
                </div>
                </li>

              ";
}
    }
// Close your database connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
div#pagination_controls{font-size:21px;}
div#pagination_controls > a{ color:#06F; }
div#pagination_controls > a:visited{ color:#06F; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h2><?php echo $textline1; ?> Paged</h2>
  <p><?php echo $textline2; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $dynamicList; ?></p>
  <div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result in browser is like this:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\pg\page.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\pg\page.php on line 68

Notice: Undefined variable: textline1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\pg\page.php on line 144
Paged

Notice: Undefined variable: textline2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\pg\page.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined variable: paginationCtrls in C:\xampp\htdocs\pg\page.php on line 147

If I change the url like this: http://localhost/pg/page.php?k=hello&q=buddy

And the code into this one:

```
<?php
// Script and tutorial written by Adam Khoury @ developphp.com
// Line by line explanation : youtube.com/watch?v=T2QFNu_mivw
include 'koneksi.php';
// This first query is just to get the total count of rows
$param = '%'.$_GET['k'].'%';
$khusus = ''.$_GET['k'].'';
$params = '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';
$khususs = ''.$_GET['q'].'';
$searchCondition = 'judul LIKE ? AND judul LIKE ? OR deskripsi LIKE ?';
$stmt=$con->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM import WHERE '.$searchCondition.'');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $param, $params, $param);
```

it works good, so i think the problem is in my looping, and how i write %

Comment: This code is a mess. There are so many things wrong here. Have you tried to debug any of your error messages, or are you just assuming we will do it for you? Each of those error messages are covered multiple times here on SO.

Comment: I've tried to debug 3 day, and i get frustated now, do you have similar code like mine? I'm so desperate...

Comment: Well, your 1st error - `Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables ... line 23`. You need to show what `$c` returns, and what `''.$g.'', $f` returns. It is clear that they don't match.

Comment: Your 2nd error - `Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables ... line 68`. You need to show what `$c` returns, and what `''.$g.'ii', $f, $begin, $end` returns. It is clear that they don't match.

Comment: Your last 3 - `Undefined variable: textline1`, `Undefined variable: textline2`, and `Undefined variable: paginationCtrls` - are all related. These variables are all set within `if ($count >= 1) {...}`. And since your query is failing (see the 1st and 2nd error messages), then `$count` is `0`, so these vars are never set, but are called in you html code at the end. Once you fix the 1st/2nd error messages, these should go away.

Comment: For 'hello buddy' words, $c = judul LIKE ? OR judul LIKE ? $f = %$z[0]%, %$z[1]% $g = ss

Comment: Try changing `$f = '%$z[0]%';` to `$f = "%$z[0]%";` (from single quotes `'` to double quotes `"`) so the variable is parsed, or to `$f = '%'.$z[0].'%';` (still with single quotes, but concatenate the `%`). Also, try changing `$x = $o . $i . $j;` to `$x =  "%{$z[$i]}%";` or `$x =  '%'.$z[$i].'%';`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, the result become like this: `$stmt->bind_param(ss, %hello%, %buddy%);` but i think its gonna work if like this: `$stmt->bind_param(ss, $z[0], $z[1]);`

Comment: You want to bind the actual variable value, ie. `"%hello%"`, not the string representation of the variable `$z[0]`. If you did `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $z[0], $z[1]);` that would work, but with your method, you are essentially doing `$stmt->bind_param('ss', '$z[0]', '$z[1]');` which means your query will be looking for the string literal `$z[0]` instead of `"%hello%"`.

Comment: Thanks for help and your patience, but our discussion will never work because "bind_param" checks each variable whether it matches the requirements. afterwards the string value is placed between quotes. [This is why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226762/mysqli-bind-param-for-array-of-strings) @Sean