# PHP: How to pass an array to bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been trying to figure this out.

```
$insertSql = 'INSERT INTO table (id,date,name,numFarts) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
$values = (1,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','Bob',5);
$bind_param_str = ('issi');
if ($stmt = $db->prepare ($insertSql)) { // $inserSql is a pre-writted sql insert
     $stmt->bind_param($bind_param_str,$values);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
}
```

This doesn't work, but I can't think of any other way to pass `$values` into `bind_param()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what the intention. How $insertSql looks like?

Comment: @lexx9999 It is generated dynamically, so I added a simple one that will essentially be it. I'm guessing the answer to this will be using `call_user_func_arr` or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Do you get an error - if so, what line and what is message? Is ID an AutoIncrement field?

Comment: @dbmitch it dies on `$stmt->bind_param(`. No error message

Comment: I don't see any arrays here.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Haha true, my bad... been a long day...

Comment: Now you can tell [why PDO should be preferred over mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#in)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah, I was just snooping your profile. Seems like you know A LOT about this stuff. Maybe I'll give it a shot. Unfortunately, the software we use to run the website is not my choice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For any function that you need to pass an array as the argument/s you can use `call_user_func_array`.

In this example:

```
array_unshift($values,$bind_param_str);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$values);
```

Don't ask me why you need `array($stmt,'bind_param')` instead of `$stmt->bind_param`. Has something to do with the syntax of  `->` I'm sure.

Comment: This won't work, but it's excusable mistake. Check the link I posted above.

Comment: Wait, you're the OP

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm still staring at this trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: it's call_user_func_array that requires a reference. However, you your PHP version is real ancient, this code would work

Comment: myphpinfo says `PHP Version 5.2.4`. I believe you are right in saying my PHP version is ancient.

Comment: Well, it's indeed not the version of your choice. It's almost TEN years old

Comment: @YourCommonSense Wow... That is much much older than I would have guessed. It's going to be real messy updating the version of PHP on our web server...

Comment: Yeah, PHP evolved a long way since then. So, remember that in case you'll update it to at least 5.3, you'll have to "referencize" the values, as it shown in the example I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The clean solution (PHP5.6+) :

```
$stmt->bind_param($bind_param_str, ...$values);
```

Comment: Did you know that there is a much easier and better way?

Comment: If I had found, I would have used it, so please enlighten me !

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/q/17226762/1839439

Comment: Thanks to @Dharman for pointing to the solution