# bind_param number of elements doesn't match number of element array

Tags: php, arrays, bind, bindparam

hello i've got a question about bind_param every code is works but not this one...probably dumb question..

```
$key = "`".implode("`, `",array_keys($notifikasi))."`";
echo $value = "'".implode("', '",array_values($notifikasi))."'";
$query = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO `notifikasi` ($key) VALUES ($value)");
$query->bind_param("iiiis",$value);
$query->execute();
```

i've echo the value :

```
'1','1','2','3','profile.php?confirm=33'
```

i've put any number on bind_param still got this error:

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables
```

anyone can answer my misunderstanding?

[**EDIT**]
nevermind, i've found the solution :
use call_user_func_array()

[mysqli bind_param for array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226762/mysqli-bind-param-for-array-of-strings)

thanks

Comment: You're not binding parameters correctly. The query string should contain placeholders like `?` or `:foo`, and not your actual values. See the docs for `bind_param` for examples.

Comment: i've read the doc yes it should put ? <br />so i put it on the prepare state (?,?,?,?,?) bind_param (iiiis,$value). <br />my question does array have something to do with it? it's still error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to bind parameters when you didn't add any placeholder for them.

You should never trust user's input so I would suggest you not to populate column names from the input. I would fix column names in query:

```
$notifikasi = [1, 2, 'profile'];
$query = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO `notifikasi` (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$query->bind_param("iis", $notifikasi);
```