# Prepared statement array explode

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, explode

I am a beginner and I am trying to use prepared statement for edit page/ form,but i dont know how use to explode with prepared statement.I want to fetch data in array data in avery input.
For this `<input type="text" name="adimpdate[]" id="adimpdate[]" value="<?php echo $row568->adimpdate; ?>" placeholder="enter">`

```
  <?php
    
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $sql011 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM detail WHERE id = ? ");
    $sql011->bind_param("i",$id);
    $sql011->execute();
    $res658=$sql011->get_result();
    ?>
<?php
 while($row658=$res658->fetch_object()){
?>

    <table>
    <tr >
    <td id="imp" class="wrap">
        <ul class="my_box">
            <input type="text" name="adimpdate[]" id="adimpdate[]" value="<?php echo $row568->adimpdate; ?>"  placeholder="enter" required>
            <button id="impbtn" type="button" name="add" onclick="add_more()">Add</button>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" id="box_count" value="1">
    </table>
    <input id="uplbtn" type="submit"  name="upload_all" value="UPLOAD">
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I used Jquery to add more input and used implode to save data in database

```
 <script>
    /**(1)*****Important Dates******** */

function add_more(){
    var box_count=jQuery("#box_count").val();
    box_count++;
    jQuery("#box_count").val(box_count);
    jQuery(".wrap").append('<ul class="my_box" id="box_loop_'+box_count+'"><input type="text" name="adimpdate[]" id="adimpdate[]"  placeholder="example- Application Begin : 22/01/2021"><button class="remove_field" type="button" onclick=remove_more("'+box_count+'")>Remove</button></ul>');
}
function remove_more(box_count){
    jQuery("#box_loop_"+box_count).remove();
    var box_count=jQuery("#box_count").val();
    box_count--;
    jQuery("#box_count").val(box_count);
}
</script>  
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226762/mysqli-bind-param-for-array-of-strings)?

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statement placeholders work somehow like php variable interpolation so to it does not replace any SQL.
You still have to use SQL `IN()` function to query by multiple values or define a single prepared statement to find by id and execute it for every entry in the array.

```
  $ids = [1, 2, 3];
  $sql011 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM detail WHERE id = ? ");
  foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $sql011->bind_param("i",$id);
    $sql011->execute();
    $res658=$sql011->get_result();
  }
```