# mysql bind_param array with where in or statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this query which works.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE item_id=? && (stage_token=? OR live_token=?)";
    
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $item, $token, $token);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

I have to rewrite it for token parameter to be array. I am not sure how to use WHERE IN with OR.

```
$parameters = str_repeat('?,', count($token) - 1) . '?'; // placeholders
$types = str_repeat('s', count($token)); //types
```

Comment: There's no  `IN` clause in the query you've shown us. But in general terms, does this answer your question? [How can I bind an array of strings with a mysqli prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226762/how-can-i-bind-an-array-of-strings-with-a-mysqli-prepared-statement)

Comment: SQL convention is to use `AND`.