# Prepared Statement with variable array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, doctrine-orm, prepared-statement

I have an array of fields I possibly want to look for in my DB:

```
$locations = array(
        2,3,5
    );
```

The number of locations can differ, and I want to create a prepared statement (with Doctrine in Symfony2) that does the same as this:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE start = 1 AND (end = 2 OR end = 3 OR end = 5)
```

(I think) I know how to use prepared statements in general, like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
  'SELECT l
  FROM AppBundle:Location l
  WHERE l.start > :start
  AND (l.end = :end1
  OR l.end = :end2
  OR l.end = :end3)
  ORDER BY l.duration ASC'
)
->setParameter('start', '1')
->setParameter('end1', '2')
->setParameter('end2', '3')
->setParameter('end3', '5');
```

but how can I do that dynamically if I do not have the size of the array?

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: MySQl has the IN function that lets you check in arrays.

Comment: Seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589626/symfony2-3-raw-sql-query-with-in-clause and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929036/how-to-use-where-in-with-doctrine-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$locations = array(
    2,3,5
);

$query = $em->createQuery(
  'SELECT l
  FROM AppBundle:Location l
  WHERE l.start > :start
  AND l.end IN :end
  ORDER BY l.duration ASC'
)
->setParameter('start', '1');
->setParameter('end', $locations);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am on the right track, but `WHERE start = 1 AND end IN("2,3,5")` gives me only one result, whereas `WHERE start = 1 AND end IN(2,3,5)` gives me all three desired. So instead of converting it to a string, I just use the locations array for the IN statement! Thank you

Comment: Fair enough, not too often I use this so a little foggy on it but if you got it working now then all is good. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Christian - Please consider editing your answer and remove the first section with the $locationsString.  It really opens things up to sql injection attacks.  Your second approach is the way to go.

Comment: @Cerad, Thanks for the advice. Made the change.

Answer (score 1):

@Christian's answer is fine, but just for the sake of completion, you can use `foreach` in order to create your SQL string.

```
<?php
$locations = array(2, 3, 5);
$endQueries = [];

foreach ($locations as $i => $location) {
    $endQueries[] = "l.end = :end{$i}";
}

$queryString = 'SELECT l
FROM AppBundle:Location l
WHERE l.start > :start
AND (' . implode(' OR ', $endQueries) . ')
ORDER BY l.duration ASC';

$query = $em->createQuery($queryString);
$query->setParameter("start", '1');

foreach ($locations as $i => $location) {
    $query->setParameter("end{$i}", $location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing fetchAll?

```
<?php
$locations = array(
    2,3,5
);

$query = $em->createQuery(
  'SELECT l
  FROM AppBundle:Location l
  WHERE l.start > :start
  AND l.end IN :end
  ORDER BY l.duration ASC'
)
->setParameter('start', '1');
->setParameter('end', $locations);

/* == Added a fetchAll call == */
$query->execute->fetchAll();

?>
```