# Selecting data from an array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have this array:

```
$ids = [1, 34, 36];
```

How do I get data from a table from each of ID using this query:

```
$query = $DB->Prepare('SELECT name, address FROM tContacts WHERE id = ?');
```

I tried using:

```
foreach ($ids AS $val) {
    $query = $DB->Prepare('SELECT name, address FROM tContacts WHERE id = ?');
    $rs = $DB->Execute($query, array($val));
    $i = 0;

    foreach($rs as $rows)
    {
        $rs[$i++]=array(
            'name'    => $rows['name'],
            'address' => $rows['address']
        );
    }
}
```

And when I tried to:

```
print_r($rs);
```

It only display the last row, not 3 rows as I intended.

Comment: Maybe WHERE id IN(?,?,?)

Comment: It's useful to do `WHERE id IN ('".join("','",$ids)."')`

Comment: Sidenote: $rs is the result from the sql query. Do not reuse it for other purposes.

Comment: Passing `array($val)` in the loop also looks wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the IN function in the SQL condition.
Combine it with a php function to repeat the placeholders N times where N is the amount of the requested IDs in the array.

```
$ids = array(1,434,23);

$query = "SELECT name, address FROM tContacts WHERE id IN('".join("','",$ids)."')";
$stmt = $DB->Prepare($query);
```

Originally i've used str_repeat, but @pokeybit came up with an idea to use join which is much more comfortable.

In case the $ids array is being built based on a user's input or so, it would be better to use the query prepare mechanism and use placeholders.

```
$count = count($ids);
$query = "SELECT name, address FROM tContacts WHERE id IN(".str_repeat('?,',$count-1)."?)"; //would output: IN(?,?,?)
```

Then, use a loop to bind the relevant IDs from the array.

**Note 1:** Both of the ideas work, one is in case the developer sets the array, the other one use the advantages of preparing queries and binding which is a better solution in case the array's in dynamic/input-based. Therefore, I've wrote both of the solutions.

**Note 2:** See @JaredFarrish last comment regarding the advantages of prepared queries.

Comment: That's invalid syntax in the `IN()`, nee the single quotes.

Comment: You need `'` outside the `".join."` bit

Comment: Also, this bypasses entirely preparing statements and condition value escaping, which can lead to invalid syntax for things other than integers and potentially security issues if values are not pre-escaped and come from untrusted sources.

Comment: @JaredFarrish he stated his array was `$ids = [1, 34, 36]` we have no other reason to suspect that array has not been validated

Comment: You're right, while it seems that the array is defined by the OP. I'll add the original answer as well (with repeated placeholders)

Comment: @OfirBaruch it should be `IN('".join("','",$ids)."')`

Comment: This is a more appropriate way to do `IN()` clauses in prepared statements (see the second code block): https://stackoverflow.com/a/330280

Comment: @JaredFarrish it's all the same as here.. they use `implode` which is 3 letters longer than `join` and does exactly the same thing

Comment: @pokeybit I don't see `bindParam()` used anywhere, and to the quotes issue, using the "OP only shows integers in an array", the quotes around the numbers don't matter.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Haha your initial post here was `That's invalid syntax in the IN(), nee the single quotes`

Comment: @pokeybit Yes, and removing the single quotes from being expressed is as appropriate as leaving them and wrapping the whole value list. This is what the answer I showed above does, it's not the same: https://3v4l.org/gCTK7

Comment: This answer by @OfirBaruch is absolutely fine. Move along please

Comment: Both of the ideas work, one is in case the developer sets the array, the other one use the advantages of preparing queries and binding which is a better solution in case the array's in dynamic/input-based. Therefore, I've wrote both of the solutions. If you have any further suggestion I would be glad to learn and to edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: There is also another benefit to using prepared queries and that's performance. If a query will be executed multiple times, using prepared statements where the query is parsed ahead of execution will be more efficient, especially if traversing a network with large `IN()` clauses.

Comment: Added a note regarding your comment which would be useful for the OP and others who would ran across this question in the future.