# get result in the same format as mysql in?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `select` where I need to scan a table to get results:

```
where (p.user in (select f from fl where user =? and block=0))
```

This table is a big table with more than 1 million rows. And it is taking a while to read. I need to read it all the time, so I was thinking I could read it once and then just use:

```
where (p.user in ($variable_with_all_results))
```

I tried:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select f from f1 where user = '1' and block = 0");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($variable_with_all_results);
```

But I cannot use this variable on the `select`, the mysql is not recognizing it. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226762/mysqli-bind-param-for-array-of-strings?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: "This table is a big table with more than 1 million rows" - if you think that is at all relevant to the performance you need to learn a little bit about database design. What matters is the number of rows matching your predicates and which of predicates match index prefixes. As to resolving the query against multiple literals - you can't do this with PDO. And regardless of the API, its probably more efficient to put the literals into a temporary table and do a join.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you want like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select GROUP_CONCAT(f) from f1 where user = '1' and block = 0");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($variable_with_all_results);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Note you need to add a `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregation function around `f` in the query, this will give you a list like `1,5,6`. Also you need to do a `fetch` on the statement to get the result into your variable.

Then you should be able to make a new query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ...
        WHERE p.user in ($variable_with_all_results)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`bind_result` wont work in that way, you should use `bind_param()`.
But using `IN (?)` won`t do.

You will need to bind each id separately, some think like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param("select f from f1 where (p.user in (select f from fl where user = IN (?,?,?,?,?) and block=0))", $id1, $id2,$id3, $id4, $id5);
```

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17228326/2271198 explain better who `bind_param` works

Comment: I will get the values (1,20,30...) from db and I'd like to use then on my next select.

Comment: Using a subselect where you could be using a join is a bad idea.